# Creating a shared memory for processes part of a MPI Communicator

Tags: c, mpi, shared-memory

The shmget function is used to create a new shared memory segment or to locate an existing one based on a key. Shared memory segments are memory areas which can be shared by several processes.
If we have an ROW MPI communicator, is it possible to create a shared memory for the processes in the communicator using the shmget() function ?

https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/
Ref for creating MPI communicator.

I intend to use the shmget function and not the MPI_win_allocate function.

Till now I have the MPI row comm setup using the code from the above tutorial.

```
// Get the rank and size in the original communicator
   int world_rank, world_size;
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

   int color = world_rank / 4; // Determine color based on row

   // Split the communicator based on the color and use the
   // original rank for ordering
   MPI_Comm row_comm;
   MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &row_comm);

    int row_rank, row_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(row_comm, &row_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(row_comm, &row_size);

    printf("WORLD RANK/SIZE: %d/%d \t ROW RANK/SIZE: %d/%d\n",
    world_rank, world_size, row_rank, row_size);

    MPI_Comm_free(&row_comm);
```

Comment: `shmget` only works for cpus/cores that are on the same _physical_ CPU cluster. That's okay if you only have one computer (e.g. your PC). But, if you have a number of computer systems (e.g. servers) spread throughout the world, `shmget` won't work too well. If you want to use shared memory, you're probably better off using `pthreads` instead of MPI. If you can identify the physical system(s), you could put one MPI node on each (possibly under separate communicators). Then, these nodes could use `pthreads` underneath and you don't even need `shmget` because the memory is already shared.

Comment: The MPI standard provides everything you need to allocate shared memory in a portable manner. So instead of wondering if you can use shmget, you should ask yourself if it is wise to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can get shared memory by MPI mechanisms: first `MPI_Comm_split_type` to get you a communicator per shared memory domain, and then `MPI_Win_allocate_shared`. You can then put your matrix row on that shared memory.

For details see https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/mpi-shared.html

Note that in general your approach doesn't work of first making a communicator per row, and then getting a shared memory on it. MPI typically runs on clusters with both distributed and shared memory, so you're limited in what processes you can group together in shared memory. Basically, that choice has been made for you.

I will also note that shared memory is hardly ever needed.

Comment: Thanks Victor, this resource seems to do the job for now. Specifically wanted shmget() function to be used for greater control on where the answer allgather and scatter functions would read and write from a node with multiple processes.